# Eager Loading: Use `with` on pivot with eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are 4 tables:

- `bundles`: id, name
- `products`: id, name
- `prices`: id, name
- `bundle_product`: id, bundle_id, product_id, price_id

There are 3 models:

- `Bundle`
- `Product`
- `Price`

A `Product` has a `Price` when in a `Bundle`. I want to have all `bundles` with their associated `products` **and associated `prices`.** I can get all bundles with their product and the price id:

```
// I created a Bundle Model with a products method
class Bundle extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('price_id');
    }
}

// Then I call this in a controller
$all_bundles = Bundle::with('products')->get();

// Then I can get the price Id of the first product of the first bundle
$price_id = Bundle::with('products')->first()
    ->products()->first()
    ->pivot->price_id;
```

But I dont want the *price id*, I want the *price Model*. Is there any way to preload the price from the pivot (with Eager Loading)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The current accepted answer deviates from the original data structure.
I created a package which can help you achieve what you want and also it maintains the original data structure. Please read my medium story here: https://medium.com/@ajcastro29/laravel-eloquent-eager-load-pivot-relations-dba579f3fd3a

First, create your custom pivot model and define relations on pivot model, in your case:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class BundleProduct extends Pivot
{
    public function price()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Price::class);
    }
}
```

Then use the pivot model in the relation:

```php
class Bundle extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
        ->withPivot('price_id') // this is needed to query the relation `price`
        ->using(BundleProduct::class);
    }
}
```

Make sure you use the trait `AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait` in the `Product` model because it is the related model in belongsToMany relation. This let us enable eager loading the pivot relations.

```php
use AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait;

class Product extends Model 
{
  use EagerLoadPivotTrait;
}
```

Then eager load it like this:

```
$bundle = Bundle::with('products.pivot.price')->first();
$price = $bundle->products->first()->pivot->price;
```

Answer (score 6):

One solution could be adding a `BundleProduct` model for the pivot. Then link the BundleProduct object to Bundle model:

```
class Bundle extends Model
{
    public function bundleProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BundleProduct::class, 'bundle_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

To get all your bundles with their associated products and prices in this bundle, just do:

```
Bundle::with('bundleProducts.product', 'bundleProducts.price')->get();
```

That worked for me, hope it could help someone else.

Comment: I was also wondering for this solution. I landed over here and solved my problem. Is it standard way to do this? @rap-2-h

Comment: Main question is about Pivot models. Eager loading which mentioned you is about HasMany relation, not ManyToMany. -1

Answer (score 2):

Documentation: [Eloquent: Relationships: Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:
>
> `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');`

That means that the `withPivot()` method only adds missing fields to the `pivot` object. To retrieve the actual `Price` model you will have to set up another relationship. It would look something like this:

```
/**
 * Class Bundle
 * 
 * Bundle model with the products relationship
 */
class Bundle extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}

/**
 * Class Product
 * 
 * Product model with the prices relationship
 */
class Product extends Model
{
    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Price::class);
    }
}

/**
 * Class Price
 * 
 * Simple model, end result
 */
class Price extends Model
{
    // Model definition...
}
```

This is basic and of course not the complete code, only the functions necessary for the answer.

After this all you need to do to retrieve relationships is the following:

```
// You can query a child relationship using the dot (.). Prices collection will be accessible within each member of the products collection 
$all_bundles = Bundle::with('products.prices')->get();

$price_id = $all_bundles->first()
    ->products->first()
    ->prices->first()->id;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. It will not work as excepted: it will return all the prices for a product and I only need the price for a product *in a bundle*. Sorry if my question was not so clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll struggle for a way to load the price model with eager loading alone, unless there is a way to pass a parent (the product, in this case) into a closure - which I'm pretty sure there isn't.

```
$all_bundles = Bundle::with(['products.prices' => function($query) use (PARENT) {
    $query->where('id', PARENT->pivot->price_id);
}])->get();
```

You could do this to load only the relevant price model, rather than all price models, after the initial query though:

```
$all_bundles = Bundle::with('products')->get();

foreach($all_bundles as $bundle) {
    foreach($bundle->products as $product) {
        $product->load(['prices' => function($query) use ($product) {
            $query->where('id', $product->pivot->price_id);
        }]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you can do to avoid N+1 query problems and without needing the eager loading package mentioned by Arjon Jason Castro:

```php
$all_bundles = Bundle::with('products')->get();
$pivotCollection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
foreach ($all_bundles as $bundle) {
    $pivotCollection = $pivotCollection->concat($bundle->products->all());
}
$pivotCollection->load('price');
```

The way it works is you collect all the pivot model instances into a new Eloquent collection and collectively call `load()` on it to invoke Laravel's logic to load the relationships for the pivots without any N+1 query problems.

Since this ensures that the same pivot instance references are updated with relations, you should be able to access any deep relation like so: `$all_bundles->first()->products->first()->price` without needing any additional DB queries.